# Creating Federation Authorization Cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, ws-federation

I have an MVC application that is federated, everything works great except the first time I load the site it doesn't pickup my authorization cookie and I have to reload the page to get authorized.  It seems what is happening is that this code:

```
 MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);

 var claims = new List<Claim>
 {
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Email),
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
 };

 var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Federation");
 var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

 var token = new SessionSecurityToken(principal);

 FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```

Is executed after the page has already loaded, then when I refresh the cookie exists so I get the results I was hoping for the first time.

I have this code in my `home` controller, it is the first page that is loaded but I am thinking maybe that is not the right place to put it, as my `_Layout` file is loaded before my `home` view and controller which I am assuming is why I am getting this result.  My question is, where should I have this code to create my federation cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isn't necessary at all! I didn't realize I could pass my AD roles as part of my federation claim.  This way I don't need to manually create a Role Provider and when the user is authenticated he/she already has the associated roles in the same claim! So much easier, wish I new this from the start would have saved many headaches and days of work!